# Can't store a java.util.Calendar object in GAE datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a GAE app that uses the java.util.Calendar class.
My app changes some internal data when a day passes/
Currently I want to test the app, so I have a fake date data-member that I set and modify manually.
I want to save it to the datastore.
After about 2 hours of trying to save it, I decided to wrap it in a class I named FakeDate. it looks like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class FakeDate {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Serialized
private Calendar _fakeCurrentDate;
```

The only problem is, the data of the _fakeCurrentDate is not saved.
At first I set the Calendar date to be 8/8/2012
When I call

```
pm.makePersistent(_currentDate);
```

It looks like everything is ok, but when I call

```
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query q = pm.newQuery(FakeDate.class);
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<FakeDate> list = (List<FakeDate>) q.execute();
        for (FakeDate f:list){
            System.out.println(f.getDayOfMonth());
            System.out.println(f.getMonth());
            System.out.println(f.getYear());
        }
    } finally {
        q.closeAll();
        pm.close();
    }
```

The FakeDate instance I get holds a Calendar instance of the date 27/9/2012. This is the default date I get when calling Calendar.getInstance()

It looks like I am missing something pretty easy. 
Am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calendar` class is not a supported field type for a datastore model. For details for the supported types take a look at [Properties and Value Types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types). If you need to have a Date field in your model, declare it as `java.util.Date` and initialize it by using `Calendar`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try and update, but shouldn't serializable objects be fine?

Comment: Serializable objects are stored as `Blob` values, if the type implements the `Serializable` interface. Since, `Calendar` does this, it should be ok. Try to change the annotation of your `_fakeCurrentDate` property to `@Persistent(serialized = "true")`.

Comment: As you can see, I added the `@Serialized` annotation, which is equivalent to `@Persistent(serialized = "true")`. Anyway, Moving to Date class did the job. It's a bit annoying to use the getTime and setTime methods all the time , but at least it works. Thanks a lot @ThanosMakris